# Match last character, get next to last if regex is null

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I'm trying to get the last character of a string, but only if it matches the following RegEx:

`/\W/`

If it doesn't match, I want it to move to the next last character and do the test again until it finds a match.

```
function getLastChar(s) {
    var l = s.length - 1;

    return s[l - i]; // need logic to keep checking for /\W/
}
getLastChar('hello.'); // returns '.', want it to return 'o'
```

I have the following idea of how to match if the character isn't a letter/number; however, I'm searching for a more elegant solution, one that would allow me to return the last matching character on a single line with a ternary `if()`

`if(string.match(/\W/) !== null){
    //keep looking for a match, going backwards.
}`

Comment: So something like `string.match(/(\w)\W*$/)`? If there's a match, it'll be at index `[1]` of the resulting array

Comment: Are you sure you want `\W` and not `\w`?  With `\W` you will only match non-word characters, so `'o'` does not match `/\W/`.

Comment: hmm.. it seems that your requirement vs. your example return value don't match. `\W` means "non-word character". So you are saying you want to match the last non-word character. Well in your example, you say it returns "." but you expect "o". But "o" is a word character.

Comment: Patrick: You should ask about the actual problem, not about what you decided was the best solution. Doing that just adds too much confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(\w)\W*$/
```

Capture one `\w` character, that is followed by zero or more `\W` characters, anchored to the end of the subject.

[Edited after comments.]

Comment: You're going to want to test your solution.

Comment: Although this does appear to be what the question is asking for, this will match the `.` in `'hello.'` which is apparently not the goal.

Comment: OP is not understanding what `\W` does, or the question is strangely phrased.

Comment: +1, the answer is correct, OP is confusing `\w` and `\W`. He did ask for the character that matches `\W`, which is the dot. If he wants to get the o, he should use `/(\w)\W*$/`

Comment: @Bergi:  The desired result is clearly described, and this doesn't do it. His phrasing of the question is a little confusing, but it appears as though he wants to match `\W` for the purpose of continuing the search backwards. *`if(string.match(/\W/) !== null){ //keep looking for a match, going backwards.`* In other words, it's somewhat of an XY Problem in that he's asking about what he presumed was the best solution.

Comment: My bad, after _“only if it matches the following RegEx: `/\W/`”_ I did not look at the example any further …

Comment: This answer matches the OP's example desired result, but it does NOT match his stated requirements

Comment: The stated requirements are all consistent except for the first part of the second sentence, which should read "matches" instead of "doesn't match".

Comment: right, and if his desired result showed he wanted to match some other foobar, then his requirements would be consistent except for some other foobar. Point is, his reqs don't match the desired output. But in my mind, "desired output" usually trumps requirements so this is probably the answer he wants

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough.. just do a greedy match up to the last `\W`

`string.match(/.*(\W)/)`

Comment: What if the string contains a line break?

Comment: @Bergi well, the OP does say "return the last matching character on a single line"

Comment: @Bergi but if OP does want to consider it, that's easily fixed: `/(?:.|\n)*(\W)/`

Comment: @Bergi .. but I may be wrong for different reasons.. his requirements do not match his example expected result!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple answer, you might be able to accomplish it with a single regex, no looping required - something like the following:

```
^.*(\W)[^\W]*$
```

The capture group will have the last non-word character.

For example, running this regex on ~~~~99*9 puts the character * in the capture group.

Edit:

However, after re-reading your question, it seems like you really meant to use \w not \W - in other words, you want the last word character, not the last non-word character.  That's easily fixed by swapping \W for \w in the regex above.